# bearer token: what kind of ClaimsIdentity has to be used in GrantResourceOwnerCredentials?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, bearer-token

This is my scenario:

I’m building a ASP Net MVC Application that communicates with a WebApi. Sometimes, I need a WebApiClient to get some data from WebApi controllers. In order to authorize my WebApiClient with current logged user credentials, I want to use access tokens with OAuth2.

My idea was to generate a token during login  and add generated token in a Claim. In order to do so, in AccountController:

```
Login(LoginViewModel model){
[...]

var signinm = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();                    
var ident = signinm.CreateUserIdentity(user);
//Generate token 
BearerToken token = await (new TokenApi()).GetToken(model.UserName, model.Password);

//Store generated token in a claim
ident.AddClaim(new Claim(WebApiClient.API_TOKEN_KEY, 
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(token)));

[…]
//Finally sign in
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(authProp, ident);

}
```

My main questions are regarding the method GrantResourceOwnerCredentials in 
ApplicationOAuthProvider:

```
public class ApplicationOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
[...]
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

        ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }

         ClaimsIdentity identity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(
                                            user,
                                            DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer);

        AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);

        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, properties);
        context.Validated(ticket);

    }

[...]
}
```

1. Do I have to generate this claimsIdentity and with which type of  DefaultAuthenticationTypes: Cookie or ExternalBearer? Both seem to work.
2. Since HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(...)  is already performed in Login, it is not necessary to signIn also in GrantResourceOwnerCredentials, am I wrong?

Thank you for your help.